# Canyon Strive AL 6.0 - SRAM GXP or a Pressfit GXP bottom bracket?

Tags: mountain-bike, bottom-bracket, sram

Does the 2016 Canyon Strive AL 6.0 Race have a SRAM GXP or a Pressfit GXP bottom bracket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a SRAM GXP in a threaded bottom bracket shell.

Here's how I found out:

The [Canyon web page](https://www.canyon.com/en/mtb/strive/2018/strive-al-6-0.html) says just 'SRAM GXP', so I looked for some reviews thinking they might provide info about the BB. [This Mountain Bike Review page](http://www.mbr.co.uk/reviews/27-5-full-suspension-bikes/canyon-strive-al-6-0-race-2016-review) has a picture that clearly shows the BB area, and you can see the bearing is an external type, not a press fit type.